# How can I measure IPC using PEBS?

Tags: x86, ipc, performancecounter

PEBS is a sampling mechanism that Intel CPUs provide for sampling performance monitors.

Is it possible to use PEBS to measure a process's IPC?  How does PEBS determine when to sample?

Answer (score 3):

Look at my answer to [Do Core i3/5/7 CPUs provide a mechanism to measure IPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018936/do-core-i3-5-7-cpus-provide-a-mechanism-to-measure-ipc) to get monitor names to count an IPC.

Yes, it is possible to use pfmon/pebs to get approximate value of IPC:

```
pfmon --smpl-module=pebs -ecpu_clk_unhalted --inv=1 --counter-mask=1 --long-smpl-periods=2660000 -uk -- foo 

pfmon --smpl-module=pebs -einstructions_retired --inv=1 --counter-mask=1 --long-smpl-periods=2660000 -uk -- foo
```

There are two runs of pfmon with pebs usage. They will give you ratio of instructions_retired and cpu_clk_unhalted samples count for entire programm and for each function.

PEBS does sample when every 2660000th event (for pfmon runs above) is in place. When pfmon starts, it asks CPU to count performance events in special msr registers. CPU will count events for process, and OS will save MSR of different processes on context_switch. Also pfmon asks CPU to give an exception when the event counter will have value >= 2660000. When the exception occurs, pfmon will record EIP of current instruction (and translate it to function name) and reset performance monitor.

PS the counting of IPC is very easy with `perf` tool from linux kernel:
https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

per-process:

```
perf stat -B -ecycles:u,instructions:u  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=2000000

2000000+0 records in
2000000+0 records out
1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 1.91559 s, 535 MB/s

 Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=2000000':

    1,993,541,603 cycles
      764,086,803 instructions             #      0.383 IPC

       1.916930613  seconds time elapsed
```

system-wide (-a switch):

```
perf stat -B -ecycles:u,instructions:u -a sleep 5

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':

      766,271,289 cycles
      596,796,091 instructions             #      0.779 IPC

       5.001191353  seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: are these vtune instructions?  is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: This is pfmon on Linux in  Precise Event-Based Sampling (PEBS) mode. http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @osgx could you please share some links which describes this mechanism: "OS will save MSR of different processes on context_switch" ?

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin, `perf`(perf_events) profiler in per-process mode will save. You may ask new question or search sources of linux kernel